# postgres indexing all columns of composite primary key

Tags: postgresql

in postgres, just checking if we need to index all columns of composite primary key

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK_TYPE(
    ID TEXT NOT NULL,   
    TYPE TEXT NOT NULL,
    LABELS HSTORE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT BOOK_TYPE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (ID,TYPE)
);
```

should I have to index ID and type separately?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create any extra index unless you happen to need it to speed up a query. The primary key will automatically create a unique index on `(id, type)`, and that is all that is needed to guarantee consistency.